# How to know the exact space setShadowLayer will need to draw a shadow?

Tags: android, android-canvas, shadow

When i do setShadowLayer with a radius of say 50px, then the width of the visible shadow (on a side) will be actually around 65px and not 50px like i was hoping. Is their any way to know to total amount of space setShadowLayer will need to draw the shadow ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use **android:elevation** in your XML but it's working on Lollipop version or above version of android. you can see this link [here](https://developer.android.com/training/material/shadows-clipping.html)

Comment: thanks but i want to know it from the canvas/paint property :(